# Definition of "good reduction"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C/\mathbb{Q}$ be a curve. I am trying to understand the difference between

> (1)  There is a model $\mathcal{C}/\mathbb{Z}$ of $C$ such that the fiber $\mathcal{C}_p$ is regular

and

> (2) $C$ has good reduction at $p$.

According to Liu's definition ("Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves", Definition 10.1.19), (2) means that $C$ admits a smooth model $\mathcal{C}'$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. How should I understand this exactly, i.e., how is this related to a model $\mathcal{C}$ of $C$ over $\mathbb{Z}$? And does (1) or (2) imply the other? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Liu's definition does not refer to a "model...over $\mathbf{F}_p$," but to a model over $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$, the localization of $\mathbf{Z}$ at the prime ideal $(p)$. For a scheme $C$ over $\mathbf{Q}$, it makes no sense to talk of a model for $C$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Sure, thanks, I will edit it

Comment: You should first  say what a curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ is, and then define what a model is precisely. Let's say a curve is a smooth proper geometrically connected one-dimensional scheme over $\mathbb{Q}$....

Comment: ....Now, if $C$ is a curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ (hence $C$ is projective over $\mathbb{Q}$), then it is not so difficult to show that $C$ has a proper model over $\mathbb{Z}$. To have good reduction at $p$ is to say that $C$ has a smooth proper model over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (or $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$). The regularity of the fibre $\mathcal{C}_p$ is equivalent to its smoothness over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Since any model is flat, this means good reduction at $p$ is in fact equivalent to $\mathcal{C}_p$ being regular (for some choice of a proper model $\mathcal{C}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p$).

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thanks for your comment. What I don't understand: $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ has only two primes $(0)$ and $(p)$. So a $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}-$model has only two fibers. How does it relate to a $\mathbb{Z}-$model? Can I see a regular $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}-$model as "a part" of a regular $\mathbb{Z}-$model whose fiber over $(p)$ is regular?